# To find product of two largest no

Tags: visual-c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int max(const vector<int>& num,int n)
{   
    int n_index=-1;
    int m_index=-1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(m_index==-1||num[m_index]<num[i])
        m_index=i;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if((i!=m_index) && (n_index==-1)||(num[n_index]<num[i]))
        n_index=i;
    }
    int product=num[n_index]*num[m_index]; 
    cout<<"output "<<num[m_index]<<" "<<num[n_index]; 
    cout<<"product "<<product;
}
int main()
{   
    int n; 
    cout<<"enter the no ";
    cin>>n;
    
    vector<int>num(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     cin>>num[i];
    max(num,n);
}
```

In the 2nd for loop in my max function after replacing "i" by "j" my code is working but if i use "i" ,why is it not working as "i" is local to that for loop ??

Comment: Be aware that `&&` has higher precedence than `||`. The condition in the second loop doesn't preclude setting `n_index == m_index`

Comment: Define "not working". What outcome do you expect, and what do you observe instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your code. It seems that the max function should be the non-return type.

```
void max(const vector<int>& num,int n)
{   
...
}
```

And the program will work with 'i'.